# how convert this patten in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working

```
newRow.replace('[[' + key + ']]', item);
```

but i tried replacing with regex but its not working

```
newRow.replace('/\[\[' + key + '\]\]/'g, item);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the RegExp constructor to use the string literal syntax.

```
newRow.replace(new RegExp('\\[\\[' + key + '\\]\\]', 'g'), item);
```

Also note that we needed to use `\\` instead of `\`. This is because the `\` has its own meaning in string literal syntax. Therefore to get a literal `\` character in the string passed to the constructor, we need to escape it.